# Installing Chromaprint - "The source directory does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt" error

Tags: cmake, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to start a project using the [AcousticID](https://acoustid.org/webservice) API which in turn requires the [Chromaprint](https://bitbucket.org/acoustid/chromaprint) library. The instructions on the Chromaprint bitbucket page are below:

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

When I attempt the first line I get the error message below:

```
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/adam" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt
```

I've searched and found various references to the error but given my lack of knowledge I can't seem to find anything I can actually action (I'm new to libraries and have never used CMake before). Is anyone able to tell me what I can do differently?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are typing below command in your home directory.

```
$ cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .
```

Change directory to the extracted sources where CMakeLists.txt belongs.